# Как str и Response преобразовать в dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
import json

url ='https://www.instagram.com/'

a = input('Введи логин пользователя с которого \nнужно собрать информацию: ')

r = requests.get(url + a)

info = {}

print(r + info)
```

Вот мой примерный код, (знаю сейчас он тут ничего не спарсит пока что) но как сделать из Response и str dict ?

Comment: Сайт https://www.instagram.com/ возвращает html, как именно вы хотите из html получить dict?

Comment: Вот вообще str или Response как заносить в dict

Comment: В dict заносится значение по какому-то ключу. Берете какой-то ключ, по этому ключу записываете какое-то значение, пример: `info[ключ] = значение`. Вот так и заносите. Если вас интересует парсинг страницы, то нужно понимать какие конкретно данные вам со страницы нужно получить - тогда можно дать какой-то конкретный ответ. А сейчас вопрос слишком абстрактный.